# Check if ID exists, and then rename it

Tags: jquery, html, duplicates

I'm trying to detect duplicate IDs,

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7ev/10/

And if I understand correctly:

```
if (id in dupeUIDCheck)
```

Checks if the value of `id` is in the array: `dupeUIDCheck`, however, it seems that the:

```
dupeUIDCheck[id] = true;
```

that is set at the end actually makes the check work.

It doesn't really look inside the:

```
dupeUIDCheck = $(document).find('DIV')
            .map(function(){ return this.id || undefined})
            .toArray();
```

for values, that I call first.

How can I fix this? For some reason I do have it working in one part of my own website, so the `makeIdUnique()` seems to be working like it should, but why doesn't it in this example? (maybe a malformed array?)

The original function was forked from a previous problem: [Renaming duplicates in Javascript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643933/renaming-duplicates-in-javascript-array)

Comment: Why dont you fix the malformed html instead of fixing it via jquery?

Comment: Because in my full script the DIVs are dynamically generated, and sometimes an element already exist, but need the ability to uniquely identify it...

Answer (score 2):

@TrySpace

As I understand "dupeUIDCheck" is a regular array. If this is true, then you need to use Array.prototype.indexOf method:

```
if (dupeUIDCheck.indexOf(id) != -1) {
 ...
}
```

This piece of code "dupeUIDCheck[id] = true;" fixes the problem because you are defining property on array object itself and "in" operator will obviously confirm that such property exists, though, this is not true for array elements. "in" operator doesn't lookup inside array elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$.inArray(id, dupeUIDCheck)
```

or

```
dupeUIDCheck.indexOf(id);
```

#### Note

As `dupeUIDCheck` is an Array, so to find an element within an array exists or not, you need to use `indexOf()`. `.indexOf()` returns `index` of the searched element within that array if found or `-1` if not found. `$.inArray(value, array)` is jQuery method which do similar job as `.indexOf()`.

---

That is

```
function makeIdUnique(id) {

   if (dupeUIDCheck.indexOf(id) >= 0) {  // exists
     // your code
   } 

}
```

or

```
function makeIdUnique(id) {

   if ($.inArray(id, dupeUIDCheck) >= 0) {  // exists
     // your code
   } 

}
```

`id in dupeUIDCheck` works for **Object** like

```
var obj = {a: 'abc', b: 'def'};
```

Then to search a property of object you can use

```
if( 'a' in obj) {

}
```

Comment: Actually, that didn't fix it yet, http://jsfiddle.net/HB7ev/13/, it will append new ones with suffixes lilke -1, -2 etc. But there are still duplicates...

Comment: @TrySpace your question is about finding array element and I my answer is about that. Your comment is about another issue which is not related about your question.Accept this answer and ask another question